# What is the most simple and proper way to fitting data to sinc function using by numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I did some work and finally i got a data that its shape looked like sinc function and i tried to search how to fitting graph to sinc function using by numpy and i found this:

[Fitting a variable Sinc function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22950301/fitting-a-variable-sinc-function-in-python)

It's good that i found it but i think why it look quite complicated?

Can you give me more friendly way to fitting graph that give me a curve like sinc function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to perform fitting the answer provided in the link you have given is good enough. But since you say you find it difficult I have an example code with data in the form a sine curve and a user defined function that fits the data.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import math

xdata = np.array([2.65, 2.80, 2.96, 3.80, 3.90, 4.60, 4.80, 4.90, 5.65, 5.92])
ydata = np.sin(xdata)

def func(x,p1,p2,p3): # HERE WE DEFINE A SIN FUNCTION THAT WE THINK WILL FOLLOW THE DATA DISTRIBUTION
    return p1*np.sin(x*p2+p3)

# Here you give the initial parameters for p0 which Python then iterates over
# to find the best fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata,p0=(1.0,1.0,1.0)) #THESE PARAMETERS ARE USER DEFINED

print(popt) # This contains your two best fit parameters

# Performing sum of squares
p1 = popt[0]
p2 = popt[1]
p3 = popt[2]
residuals = ydata - func(xdata,p1,p2,p3)
fres = sum(residuals**2)

print(fres) #THIS IS YOUR CHI-SQUARE VALUE!

xaxis = np.linspace(1,7,100) # we can plot with xdata, but fit will not look good 
curve_y = func(xaxis,p1,p2,p3)
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'*')
plt.plot(xaxis,curve_y,'-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also visit this [website!!](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=5215) and learn step by step about how curve_fit works.